# I don't understand what I changed

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

One hour ago, I spend a lot of time and finished the project but I had problems when saving it properly and totally lost it. However, I did it again but this time it don't work

I am not sure what I did wrong this time... I think I did exactly the same, but this time don't work?

**I am getting the following error:**

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Program.convertir(string)'   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\modifiedForPersonalReasons\Program.cs    12  45  ConsoleApplication1

Here is my code, I was going to put just the error lines but then it would probably miss some information that we could need to spot the problem:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("23.21 es " + convertir("23.21"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string convertir(string str)
    {
        string[] arr;
        arr = str.Split('.');

        string rtn = españolizar(arr[0], "peso");

        if (arr.Length > 1)
        {
            rtn += " con " + españolizar(arr[1], "centavo");
        }

        return rtn;
    }

    public string españolizar(string str, string str2)
    {
        string[] list1 = { "cero", "un", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve", "diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince" };
        string[] list2 = { "nivelarindexes", "dieci", "veinti", "trei", "cuare", "cincue", "sese", "sete", "oche", "nove" };

        int numero = int.Parse(str);
        string strNumero = Convert.ToString(numero);

        int primerDigito = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(strNumero[0]));
        int segundoDigito = 0;

        if (strNumero.Length > 1)
        {
            segundoDigito = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(strNumero[1]));
        }

        int cases = -1;

        if (numero > -1 && numero < 16)
        {
            cases = 0;
        }
        else if (numero > 15 && numero < 30)
        {
            cases = 1;
        }
        else if (numero > 29 && numero < 100)
        {
            cases = 2;
        }
        else if (numero == 100)
        {
            cases = 3;
        }

        string rtn = "";

        switch (cases)
        {
            case 0:
                rtn = list1[numero] + " " + str2;
                if (primerDigito != 1)
                {
                    rtn += "s";
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (numero != 20)
                {
                    rtn = list2[primerDigito] + list1[segundoDigito];
                }
                else
                {
                    rtn = "veinte";
                }
                rtn += " " + str2 + "s";
                break;
            case 2:
                rtn = list2[primerDigito] + "nta";
                if (segundoDigito != 0)
                {
                    rtn += " y " + list1[segundoDigito];
                }
                rtn += " " + str2 + "s";
                break;
            case 3:
                rtn = "cien " + str2 + "s";
                break;
            case -1:
                rtn = "número invalido";
                break;
        }

        rtn = rtn.Replace("iun", "iún").Replace("idos", "idós").Replace("itres", "itrés").Replace("iseis", "iséis");

        return rtn;
    }
```

I could swear I didn't change anything :C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `public string convertir(string str)` to `public static string convertir(string str)`. Do the same for the españolizar function.

Comment: Españolizar function will need the same change, don't it?

Comment: `23.21 es veintitrés pesos con veintiún centavos` :D. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this message because you are calling non-static methods from a static method.  You need an instance of this class to call the non-static methods, or make the other methods static.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your two methods to `static` methods as you can't call a static method from a non-static method.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017708/why-cant-you-call-a-non-static-method-from-a-static-method) for an explanation as to why.

To fix this, you must change the following:

```
public string convertir(string str)
```

To

```
public static string convertir(string str)
```

And change

```
public string españolizar(string str, string str2)
```

To

```
public static string españolizar(string str, string str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The convertir method needs to be static (same as Main).