# Unable to perform simple method call

Tags: c#

How do I get the following program to print the result of sumOfNumbers method? I was unable to call this method in the main method and I'm not sure why. Can someone explain what I have done wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //Console.WriteLine();
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private int sumOfNumbers (int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some of the solutions below remove the static Main method. While this addresses the question, `Program.Main` is usually the entry point for a console application, so this approach isn't useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method has the wrong signature. It should be `private static int sumOfNumbers(int x, int y)` .

edit: I've been asked to put a little more explanation around this. A static method, like `Main` in your example, doesn't belong to a particular instance of an object. It belongs to its class, `Program`. A method without the static modifier belongs to a particular instance of the class. This difference means that an "objectless" static method (`Main`) can only work directly with methods that are static, or by instantiating an object and then invoking that method on the object.

This second method would look like:

```
var foo = new Program();
Console.WriteLine(foo.sumOfNumbers(3,2))
```

I would continue to recommend modifying the method to be static. I infer from your `Main` method that you're writing a console app, and it would be unconventional (in my experience) to instance such a class.

Comment: at least explain why, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017708/why-cant-you-call-a-non-static-method-from-a-static-method

Comment: Just for clarification, the reason why the OP can't see the `sumOfNumbers` method is because you can't call an *instance* method from a `static` method.

Comment: Fantastic that's very clear thank you. I will read up more regarding method signatures.

Answer (score 2):

you either need to instantiate your `Program` and call `sumOfNumbers`, or you can make `sumOfNumbers` static.

```
var program = new Program();
var sum = program.sumOfNumbers(1, 2);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Or, if you put the `static` keyword in front of your `sumOfNumbers` implementation, then you could call it with `Program.sumOfNumbers(1, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Understanding about "static" keyword would help you. Refer
[What's a "static method" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

The concept here is, one method is "static" method and other method is "instance" method.

You cannot call instance method from a static method without instanciating the class. However vice-versa should be possible.

Hence if you convert your method signature as,

```
private static int sumOfNumbers (int x, int y)
```

you can able to call this method from main(), a static method

Answer (score 0):

Summing up:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Writeline(sumOfNumbers(5,5));
    }

    private static int sumOfNumbers (int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write the following code in main

```
Program p=new Program();
Console.Write(p.sumOfNumbers(<any number>,<any number>);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: While this is true, `Program` is usually the entry point for a console application, so this approach isn't useful.

Answer (score -2):

Console.Writeline(sumOfNumbers(5,5).Tostring);

Comment: You don't need `ToString`, nor would this work because the method signature has not been marked as `static`.