# An object reference is required C# CS0120

Tags: c#, variables, methods

This question has been asked to death but i cannot take from those answers what my problem is.

All i want to do is :

1. Declare my global bool variable (used as a flag for later.)
2. Run my method to do a check, in which it will change the global variable

Anybody able to explain why this isn't working? Thanks.

```
    class Program
    {
        public bool onVPN;

         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckVPN();
            CheckIfInternal();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void CheckVPN()
        {
            NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
            {
                //crude way to check if the VPN adapter is running
                if (adapter.Description == "VPN Adapter")
                {
                   onVPN = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    onVPN = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to add `static` to the declaration of CheckVPN and onVPN. And probably CheckInternal but that isn't shown.

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? What is the behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    public static bool onVPN;

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CheckVPN();
        CheckIfInternal();
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void CheckVPN()
    {
        NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
        {
            //crude way to check if the VPN adapter is running
            if (adapter.Description == "VPN Adapter")
            {
               onVPN = true;
            }

            else
            {
                onVPN = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Changes applied, are added `static` keyword to `onVPN` field, and to method `CheckVPN`.

More explanation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options here

1.change `CheckVPN()` signature to static and the variable `onVPN` to static as well, you can find the reason why you have to add `static` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017708/why-cant-you-call-a-non-static-method-from-a-static-method)

2.create new class and put your code there as it is, and then on your main class you can do something like this

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.CheckVPN();
```